# AWS identity in github actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, github-actions, cicd

I need access to my AWS account in my github actions. Here is an overview of my github actions workflow.

```
- workflows/main.yaml
- actions/backend/action.yaml
- actions/terraform_ecr/action.yaml
- actions/terraform_lambd/action.yaml
- actions/set-up/action.yaml
```

So my `main.yaml` will look for changes in some folders and call their respective workflow. In my `setup` step from my `main.yaml` I will configure my AWS account like this.

```
# main.yaml

setup:
    needs: changes
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: configure AWS
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: eu-central-1
      - name: setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.10.9
      - name: setup
        uses: ./.github/actions/set-up
        with:
          POETRY_VERSION: 1.4.0
```

I do this because my other workflows also need this access. So I want to test to see if my account is rightly configured. By adding this step in the workflows.

```
- name: Test aws creds
    shell: bash
    run: aws sts get-caller-identity
```

In my `action.yaml` from my `lambda` folder I get this error.
[image]

But when I execute the same command in the `backend` `action.yaml` I get this output.

```
{
    "UserId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Account": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:user/dXXXX.bXXXX@XXXXXXX.XX"
}
```

Does anyone know why my `backend` `action.yaml` can access it but my `lambda` `action.yaml` can not access this? All help is greatly appreciated

#### EDIT

To give a better overview of how the workflows flow together.
This is my `workflows/main.yaml`

```
name: Main workflow
on: [pull_request, push]
jobs:
  changes:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      backend: ${{ steps.changes.outputs.backend }}
      ecr: ${{ steps.changes.outputs.infra }}
      lambda: ${{ steps.changes.outputs.lambda }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
      id: changes
      with:
        base: ${{ github.ref }}
        filters: |
          ecr:
            - 'terraform_ecr/**'
          backend:
            - 'scraper_backend/**'
            - 'app.py'
            - 'tagging.sh'
          lambda:
            - 'terraform_lambda/**'
  setup:
    needs: changes
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: configure AWS
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: eu-central-1
      - name: setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.10.9
      - name: setup
        uses: ./.github/actions/set-up
        with:
          POETRY_VERSION: 1.4.0
  ecr:
    needs: [changes, setup]
    if: ${{ needs.changes.outputs.ecr == 'true' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: ecr
        uses: ./.github/actions/terraform_ecr

  backend:
    needs: [changes, setup, ecr]
    if: ${{ needs.changes.outputs.backend == 'true' }}
    
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      AWS_REGION: eu-central-1
      ECR_REPO_NAME: etl_pipeline_test
      AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: 667193245318
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: backend
        uses: ./.github/actions/backend
        with:
          ECR_REPO_URI: ${{ env.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}.dkr.ecr.${{ env.AWS_REGION }}.amazonaws.com/${{ env.ECR_REPO_NAME }}
          AWS_REGION: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}
          ECR_REPO_NAME: ${{ env.ECR_REPO_NAME }}
          AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: ${{ env.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}


  lambda:
    needs: [changes, setup, ecr, backend]
    if: ${{ needs.changes.outputs.lambda == 'true' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: lambda
        uses: ./.github/actions/terraform_lambda
        with:
          AWS_REGION: eu-central-1
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
```

So to explain a bit. We have `4` steps, `setup`, `ecr`, `backend` and `lambda`. The goal of this workflow is to only call the workflows in which the files where changed. Now in my `setup` I configure my AWS creds like this.

```
- name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

The problem now is that I need this creds in all my workflows (ecr, backend and lambda). Now we can take a look at the `backend` workflow.

```
name: Terraform ECR
description: Build and push docker image to ECR

inputs:
  ECR_REPO_URI:
    description: 'ECR repository URI'
    required: true
  AWS_REGION:
    description: 'AWS region'
    required: true
  ECR_REPO_NAME:
    description: 'ECR repository name'
    required: true
  AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:
    description: 'AWS account ID'
    required: true

runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - name: Test aws creds
      shell: bash
      run: aws sts get-caller-identity
    - name: Create tag for build
      shell: bash
      id: tagging
      run: >-
          echo "tag=$(./tagging.sh -u ${{ inputs.ECR_REPO_URI }} -r ${{ inputs.AWS_REGION }})"
          >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    - name: Check tag
      shell: bash
      run: echo ${{ steps.tagging.outputs.tag }}
    - name: build, and push image to amazon ECR with tag
      env:
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{ steps.tagging.outputs.tag }}
      shell: bash
      run: |
        docker build -t ${{ inputs.ECR_REPO_URI }}:$IMAGE_TAG . && docker push ${{ inputs.ECR_REPO_URI }}:$IMAGE_TAG
    - name: build, and push image to amazon ECR with latest tag
      shell: bash
      run: |
        docker build -t ${{ inputs.ECR_REPO_URI }}:latest . && docker push ${{ inputs.ECR_REPO_URI }}:latest
```

To explain I need the aws creds for the `tagging.sh` script. but as you can see I never configure the creds in this workflow explicitly. Now I'm coming to the problem, why can this workflow access these creds and my lambda workflow cannot?
this is the lambda workflow.

```
name: Terraform Lambda
description: Update or build lambda and s3 buckets with terraform
inputs:
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:
    description: 'AWS access key ID'
    required: true
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:
    description: 'AWS secret access key'
    required: true
  AWS_REGION:
    description: 'AWS region'
    required: true
runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
  - name: configure aws creds
    shell: bash
    run: aws configure set aws_access_key_id ${{ inputs.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }} && aws configure set aws_secret_access_key ${{ inputs.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }} && aws configure set default.region ${{ inputs.AWS_REGION }}
  - name: init terraform
    shell: bash
    run: cd terraform_lambda && terraform init  
  - name: init ECR
    shell: bash
    run: cd terraform_ecr && terraform init
  - name: set ECR REPO URL
    shell: bash
    id: ecr_repo_url
    run: echo "ECR_REPO_URL=$(cd terraform_ecr && terraform output ecr_repository_url)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  - name: 'Lambda Terraform'
    shell: bash
    run: cd terraform_lambda && terraform apply -var "ecr_repo_uri=${{ steps.ecr_repo_url.outputs.ECR_REPO_URL }}" -auto-approve
```

You can see in this workflow I did configure them again as this seemed to be the only thing that worked. If anyone has idea's feel free to share. Every help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Before testing in that action, have you configured the creds? Or, you're trying to do this only once? Please add the relevant parts of both actions (main and lambda) in your question.

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into my problem. The creds get configured in the setup which all the workflows are dependant on so they are configured before testing the workflow. Also in the lambda workflow is nothing which has anything to do with the config of the creds. BTW I found a fix, i just configure them in my lambda but if you find something to configure them once you are welcome to still share this!

Comment: Hi! Looks like you need to update your complete workflow including those actions. It's not clear whether you're using all those action in one job or multiple ones. Jobs run in different runners. The creds configuration action sets up the env vars which may only be available for the next steps in the same job.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation correctly, you are configuring your AWS credentials at a certain job, and you try to access them from a different job, correct?

The `aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2` action will save the various AWS keys and secrets in the GitHub env of the current job, and only it.
Other jobs/workflows won't be able to access it.

You need to run the `aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2` action in every job that you need it.

You can read more here about passing variables between jobs: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#passing-values-between-steps-and-jobs-in-a-workflow.

Comment: That I get but then why can 1 workflow access this and the other cannot? Because I cannot configure it in the other workflows because they dont allow an `uses` step.

Comment: Please update your original question with the rest of your workflows so we can have a better look.

Comment: Hi @Yonatan  I have updated the question hopefully this gives a better understanding of the problem.